# Alteração de tags automaticamente

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, html-tags

Estou criando um função para envio de e-mail via nodemailer, e nosso tenho alguns templates que são para casos especifícos.

Preciso de uma função que assim que receba o template de Bem vindo por exemplo, altere alguns campos (tags) de forma automática.

Por exemplo, vou enviar: `'Olá {Nome}, bem vindo!'`

Preciso que pegue o valor do banco de dados e altere, por exemplo: 'Olá `{Nome, bem vindo!'` > `'Olá João, bem vindo!'`

Ou também de login: `'Seu login é {Login}'`.

Preciso que pegue do MySQL.

(Código de exemplo)

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'test@mail.com',
  to: 'testuser@.com',
  subject: 'Testes de envio de e-mail',
  html: '<p>Seu usuário é {Usuario} e senha é {Senha}</p><p>Olá {Nome}, seja bem vindo!'
};
```

Comment: Já pensou em usar [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)?

Comment: Se a resposta abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma função que extraia os parâmetros e substitua pelos valores respectivos como a seguinte:

```js
// Substitui na String de texto a assinatura entre "{}" pelo valor no objeto
const repor = (texto, assinatura, valor) => texto.replace(new RegExp(`{${assinatura}}`, 'ig'), valor);

const substituir = (texto, valores) => {
  // Percorre as chaves para gerar o texto substituído
  const conteudo = Object.keys(valores).reduce((acumulador, assinatura) => repor(acumulador, assinatura, valores[assinatura]), texto);

  return conteudo;
};

console.log(substituir('Olá {Nome}, bem vindo!', { Nome: 'José' }));
console.log(substituir('Nome: {Nome}\nIdade: {Idade}', { Nome: 'José', Idade: 42 }));
```

É interessante que você faça essa substituição no servidor, assim você tem controle sobre a versão em que o código é executado e garante que haverá suporte às funcionalidades que são utilizadas na implementação da função.